# connection property not initialized

Tags: c#, connection, oledb

I've been trying many different commands and arrangements for this. This is a simple program for entering new contacts into a database. My first database stuff. I have simple text boxes that accept only letters then the zip code which will accept only numbers. Not sure exactly why my "executenonquery()" says "Connection property has not been initialized." What am I missing?

```
    string connection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Documents and Settings\\Sales\\My Documents\\Google Drive\\Home\\Contacts\\Contacts.accdb";
        string command = "INSERT INTO [Contacts] (First Name, Last Name, Address, City, State/Province, ZIP/Postal Code) VALUES (@fname, @lname, @address, @city, @state, @zip)";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connection);
        OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        conn.Open();
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First Name", fname);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last Name", lname);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", address);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", city);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State/Province", state);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZIP/Postal Code", zip);
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the double slashes from the connection string?

Also, you might run into an error in your SQL Statement because I don't think that "State/Province" or "ZIP/Postal Code" are valid column names. Try surrounding them with square brackets `[ ]`

Comment: that gives a "unknown escape sequence".

Answer (score 3):

Change this line:

```
OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand();
```

... to these two lines:

```
OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(conn);
comm.commandText = command;
```

Your command object needs to have a reference to an open connection (which we get by using the constructor that takes a connection object), and your command object also needs to have its command text property set (otherwise the system has no idea what query you're trying to run).

**Edit:** whoops, haven't used these guys in awhile. All you actually need is this one line:

```
OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(command, conn);
```

Comment: now it is saying that the OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(conn); has some invalid arguments.

Comment: And remove that OleDbDataAdapter not needed and not used

Comment: Now there is a SYNTAX in my INSERT INTO statement. do I need [] around the column names I want to insert into?

Comment: Field names with a space in them need to be surrounded by []. I'm not exactly sure what to do with a column name like "State/Province". To make your life easier, I would just go to the database and rename any columns with spaces or "/" in them.